# Why can't I call a private method when I'm inside a public method?

Tags: python, private, public

I have the following code:

```
class MyClass:
    def __private(self):
        print "Hey man! This is private!"

    def public(self):
        __private()
        print "I don't care if you see this!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = MyClass()
    x.public()
```

However it gives me the following error:

`NameError: global name '_MyClass__private' is not defined`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also, if you haven't already, read this section of the documentation: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables Single underscores are the typical convention for "private" variables. You typically only use double underscores when you want to avoid name clashes in classes that inherit from your `MyClass`. Double underscores will invoke name mangling, which may be what you wanted here, but I wanted to make sure you're aware of it...

Comment: Please do not use `__`.  It's reserved for "name mangling", a thing Python does internally to make sure the internal names never collide.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need `self`:

```
self.__private()
```

Classes in python take getting used to if you're coming from C#/C++/Java, like it looks like you are.  This is probably butchering the "pythonic" way of wording things, but you can think about it like this (it helped me out):

Each class defines a namespace defined from within itself as `self` and from without by the name of an instance of that class.  "Private" things with two underscores get mangled so that from without you have to call it by a special name, but from within you can simply use `self.__private()`.

As Joe mentioned in his comment normal private variables are typically just named with a single underscore, the double underscore mangles it so inheritance can work without name clashes in sub-classes.  There's no enforcement of privacy in python, it's purely convention that says you can't use a private variable from outside the class.

As Thomas mentioned, `self` is also a convention.  For any method (a function declared as part of a class) the instance that the method is being called on is the first parameter passed in.  You could just as easily do this:

```
def __private(randomText):
    print "Hey man! This is private!"

def public(otherRandomText):
    otherRandomText.__private()
    print "I don't care if you see this!"
```

However, if you do that the spirits of logic and good programming style will haunt you and your descendants for all eternity.  (`self` is much preferable).

Any pythonistas wish to correct/further-explain?

Comment: Don't worry about it man! I can't tell you how many times I've done that.  It'll probably keep happening whenever you switch between languages.

Comment: @Bob @Cpfohl Yup, catches me out every time in PHP, too, just because I spent so many years doing C++...

Comment: Wonderful explanation. You were right in assuming that I was coming from a C-Style language (C#).

Comment: @Bob: I cheated and looked at your tags... ;-)

Comment: Strictly speaking, the name `self` is a convention, not hardcoded. Any methods of a class get the instance automatically passed as the first variable, and we use self to refer to that. This is academic, though: I've never seen a reason to call it anything other than self.

Answer (score 3):

Your code as is is trying to call a static function MyCalls.__private, you want to do this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __private(self):
        print "Hey man! This is private!"

    def public(self):
        self.__private()
        print "I don't care if you see this!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = MyClass()
    x.public()
```